# Nginx ssl_certificate based on $host?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

Hello how can I base `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` based on `$host` so I am able to do:

`if $host = domain.com than set one path, if $host = example.com than set another path`?

I am using `nginx/1.15.8`

If I make different blocks for the domains I am getting an error on reloading:

`nginx: [emerg] duplicate zone "cache"` therefore I need 1 block and to load the certificates based on the domain.

Comment: What the problem with two separate server blocks? Just don't create duplicate cache zone.

Comment: @AlexeyTen server blocks can get very large (although they shoudn't if includes were used properly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive substitutions:

```
map $host $certfile {
    domain.com    /path/to/certificate_1;
    example.com   /path/to/certificate_2;
}
map $host $keyfile {
    domain.com    /path/to/key_1;
    example.com   /path/to/key_2;
}

server {
    ...
    ssl_certificate        $certfile;
    ssl_certificate_key    $keyfile;
    ...
}
```

### Update 1

As @AlexeyTen noted, this config requires nginx >= 1.15.9, so it won't work for nginx 1.15.8 (or the latest openresty production release 1.15.8.3). If you're using openresty, the only way to use this config is to manually build and install 1.17.8.1 RC1.

### Update 2

As an alternative you can request a new certificate which would be valid for both domains. I did it for myself with [this](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) bash script using the following command:

```
acme.sh --issue -d domain.com -d example.com --webroot /my/web/root
```

Comment: that requires nginx >= 1.15.9

Comment: Thank you, Ill try to upgrade and see what happens

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab Alternatively you can get one certificate for both domains.

Comment: Both domains with 1 certificate? I have 1 existing certificate from letsencrypt for the one domain, is there a way to add the second domain to that certificate?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to add new domain to existing certificate )) But you can request new certificate from letsencrypt which would contain both domains.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab see the second update for the answer.

Comment: thank you soo much, one small detail to ask, /my/web/root is the root of the website on server right?

Comment: Yes, and it must be the same for both domains. And letsencrypt will query your site with plain HTTP protocol on port 80, you should listen to this port at least while acquiring the certificate (no 301 redirections etc.)

Comment: As a side note that cost me way too long to figure out. When using variables for your `ssl_certificate` or `ssl_certificate_key` you will get a permissions denied error when running Nginx as a non-root user. You need to fix the permissions for this to work this way.

Comment: @Jeremy what in particular did you do to fix these permissioning issues for the dynamic cert files? Not looking to run nginx as root ofc. Is it just ownership that a different group should have?

Comment: @mochsner I don't work on this project anymore but from what I can recall, I had to change the permissions for the key/cert for it to work. I set the user/group for these to be `nginx`. I am not 100% on this but that is what I recall.

Comment: @mochsner I found the project I was working on that had this issue. It looks like my solution was to add GROUP `read` and `execute` permissions to the files: `chmod g=rX ./ssl/live/*`

Answer (score 2):

Overall, the voted solution is incorrect: $host variable is not populated unless tls termination takes place.

The correct solution is described in here: https://jjj.blog/2019/05/variable-ssl-certificate-directives-in-nginx-part-2/

Comment: This is correct. The SSL/TLS handshake (i.e., the negotiation of the encryption protocol and validation of the certificate) occurs before the HTTP header (with the $host) is read by the server. Then it can result, that nginx just delivers the default ssl_certificate, and if the current domain is not included, it will result in an ssl error.